# Not able to Ajax post knockout (KO) data in XML format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, knockout.js

I am working on .NET 4.0 MVC project. I am trying to Ajax post a piece of data from my KO model. That data is a string in following XML format.

```
<SearchCriteria><Criteria SearchOn="Name" SearchValue="test 3" /></SearchCriteria>
```

I am trying to post it like this.

```
$.ajax({
        url: destUrl,
        data: ko.toJSON(DataToPost()),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            // I am doing my stuff here.
            }
        },
        error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(request.statusText);
        }
    });
```

Here you will notice the data being sent is `"ko.toJSON(DataToPost())"`. `DataToPost()` returns the `XML` string contained in my `KO model` data member `DataToPost`. `ko.toJSON()` is used to convert the `KO model` data in `JSON`.

This throws a runtime exception which is normally `thrown` when we post anything containing `javascript` or `html` tags. This is a security feature by `.NET`. Following is the exception.

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client.

&lt;SearchCriteria&gt;&lt;Criteria SearchOn=&quot;...est 3\&quot; /&gt;&lt;/SearchCriteria&gt;
```

I faced similar situation sometimes back (though I was not using `KO` that time and it was normal post i.e. non `Ajax`). I overcame the problem that time by using `javascript` `escape()` but this time it `failed`. I used it as follows

```
$.ajax({
    url: destUrl,
    **data: ko.toJSON(escape(SearchCriteria()))**,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        // I am doing my stuff here.
        }
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(request.statusText);
    }
});
```

Other popular fix is to disable this security either at page level or at application level. It could be done as follows.

**Page level.**

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

**Application level.**

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But doing away with this security is not good. I don't think it will be a wise move. Right now I don't know what to do. Need suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Knockout question. It's really about posting xml data to asp.net. Request validation kicks in in .NET 4.0 before the beginRequest. Change you web.config to this.

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Now add the `ValidateInput` attribute to your specific action method.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

This should allow the data through without compromising your whole sites request validation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I too thought to do it like this but this will be like compromising with security. I am not comfortable with. So I rather thought to go for different approach. Check my reply to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it is difficult to `serialize` an `XML` formatted string hence instead of `XML` formatted string I decided to post List of `Key value pair` instead. This approach is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hei, just pass that xml as string and decode that in server side instead of serializing that in client side. Can you post your html too because I am sure you can doing something wrong on button submit.